# Easiest way to call a method in another class?

Tags: objective-c

Of anything in Objective C this drives me the most insane time and time again. (please excuse me if I have any terminology wrong)

(using Arc)

Using [ddmenucontroller](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController) I load 2 menu's similar to the Facebook App; leftcontroller and rightcontroller

In RightController.h and m I pull an httprequest and load a list of friends.
Loaded from LeftController.h and m, I have a add friends view controller.

When a friend is added from AddFriendsViewController.h and m, I need to update the list of friends in RightController by calling -(void) getFriends

I've tried notifications, I've tried setting up shared instances, nothing seems to work for me :( My biggest problem from most of the examples I've seen is I still need to call getFriends on viewDidLoad in RightController.m and everytime I change, it, I crash when loading RightController

Please let me know what code anyone would like to see; I've removed everything I tried as it wasn't working...

Answer (score 1):

You need to abstract your download and data storage away from the views and view controllers (think MVC). Perhaps have a singleton to manage all of your data. Now, any view controller can trigger new downloads and any view controller can observe new data. If your singleton gets new data, just post the notification. In your view controllers, add as an observer when they are shown and remove when they are hidden. View controllers can also check for new data at any time by explicitly calling the singleton.

---

Your singleton interface could be something like:

```
#define MY_NEW_DATA_NOTIFICATION @"MY_NEW_DATA_NOTIFICATION"

@interface MyDataController : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *downloads;

+ (MyDataController *)sharedController;

- (void)startDownload;

@end
```

Comment: That somewhat makes sense. Could you post an example or a link to an example please?

Comment: Definitely pay attention to what Wain said about abstracting your download and data storage away from the views and view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Wain: your answer put me on the right track

RightController.h

```
@interface RightController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *offerArray;
    NSArray *find_list;

    UITableView *myTableView;
    NSMutableArray *dataSource;
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    NSMutableArray *addrData;

}
+ (RightController *)sharedController;

-(void) getFriends;

@end
```

RightController.m

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getFriends) name:@"rightControllerGetFriends" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and AddFriendsViewController.m

```
- (IBAction) TellAFriendPressed:(id)sender
{
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"rightControllerGetFriends"
                                                            object:nil];

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, what you've done here is ignore the important part (the separation of concerns) and take the code snippet and apply it in totally the wrong way. It might work, but that doesn't make it right / good / nice... Read about MVC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)? This is the kind of thing it was created for.